# ElasticSearch Range within a list

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a list of datetimes in a document in a field called eventDateTimes.  I want to know if the document has a an eventDate greater or equal to a search date.

```
"eventDateTimes": [
              "2014-03-04T23:25:48",
              "2014-05-06T00:00:05",
              "2014-06-05T00:00:05",
              "2014-07-01T00:00:05",
           ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is stored as a `date` in Elasticsearch, you can simply use a range filter:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/date_range/test/_search" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
           "filter": {
               "range": {
                  "eventDateTimes": {
                     "from": "2014-03-04T23:25:48"
                  }
               }
           }
        }
    }
}'
```